# Can I find out which operating system created a file?

Tags: operating-systems

I have some files. All of them were created in different operating systems.

Is there any way to identify from which OS each file was generated?

Comment: Not for all (most) files.

Comment: Are these simple text files?

Comment: I can generate a Word .doc file on Windows, or Linux (with LibreOffice). It would be impossible in the general sense. I can generate a Windows (line ending) text file on any OS.

Comment: What sort of files are they? Providing more details may result in a better answer.

Comment: What's the original problem? Or, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 7):

In general, no, not really.

In practice, it *may* be possible, but it depends on the file and the disk. If it is a text-file, you *may* be able to identify the OS that created it by the line-breaks:

```
CR+LF = Windows
LF    = Linux
CR    = Mac
```

Of course these are only the *default* line breaks used and there are text editors for each OS that can allow you to manually specify what to use.

If it is a binary file, then there will likely be a file-format that governs the format of its contents, so there is no way to know what OS created it.

You may be able to get a clue as to the originating OS from the disk itself. You could examine the type of the partition, but again it is not a guarantee since most modern OSes support most of the common partition types.

You may also be able to glean some information about the origin of the file via its meta-data (if any).

Comment: `CR` would be only Mac OS Classic, no? *(side note: I've seen LF+CR once in something Novell-related)*

Comment: Maybe it was Cherry Mac. `:-D` Yes, probably only System* because OSX is Linux based, so I think it uses `LF`. The lone `CR` is still called Mac style though since few (if any) other OSes did it that way.

Comment: *Unix-based (Mach+BSD)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the file type you may actually end up with a sound heuristic (Synetech pointed out one for text files.)
However, if you were hoping for some kind of fingerprint inherent to all files an OS generates, ([as with tcp/ip implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_fingerprinting)) I don't think anything the like exists so far.